# Change css class with js

Tags: javascript, css

I want to add and remove css class when the window's width is smaller than 768px.
I used javascript to do this :

```
$(window).ready(function() {
 var $width = $(window).width();
  if ($width <= 768){
   $('header').addClass('hide');
   $('#menu-switch').removeClass('hide');
 };
});
```

The problem is that I've to refresh the page so that it works. Is there a way to add and remove class without need to refresh the page ?

Comment: Yes, it's called the `resize` event !

Comment: yes use `resize` event.

Comment: Use the resize event?

Comment: This is what [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) are for.

Comment: That not correct aproach as it is very heavy as it runs constantly on resize. Try css, take a look in my answer below.

Comment: Find both the jQuery way, and the (better) CSS media queries way in my answer below.

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna use media queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery way would be

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
   if ($(window).width() <= 768){
      $('header').addClass('hide');
      $('#menu-switch').removeClass('hide');
   }
   else {
      $('#menu-switch').addClass('hide');
      $('header').removeClass('hide');
   }
});
```

but you shouldn't use this since there is a much more performant way to do this in CSS via so-called media queries. Your solution for the usecase you showed would look like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    header {
       display: none;
    }
    #menu-switch {
       display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    header {
       display: block;
    }
    #menu-switch {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
var $width = $(window).width();
  if ($width <= 768){
   $('header').addClass('hide');
   $('#menu-switch').removeClass('hide');
 };
};
```

Comment: Why would you use jQuery everywhere else *except* when binding the handler to the onresize event? That's arguably the *best* opportunity to use jQuery because it avoids overwriting the existing handler (or having this one overwritten later.)

Comment: Because jQuery is just wrapping the standard resize DOM event.

Comment: ...with the added benefits I just mentioned.

Comment: You are right, I thought that both were exactly equals.

Answer (score 0):

That can be done with css for a smoother rendering as window resize listener is quite heavy for users with low perfomance computers.

Try somethink like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 header, #menu-switch {
   display: none;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(window).on('resize', function(){ ....
```

We've had to use the same idea to fix css on resize previously. We also added some delay and trigged the resize event ourselves as well on document ready just to be sure.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  jQuery(window).trigger('resize');
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```js
$(window).bind('load resize', function(){
 var $width = $(window).width();
  if ($width <= 768){
   $('header').addClass('hide');
   $('#menu-switch').removeClass('hide');
 };
});
```

Comment: Please note that the use of `bind(events, callback())` is discouraged in favor of `on(events, callback())`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function(){
    var $width = $(window).width();
    if ($width <= 768){
        $('header').addClass('hide');
        $('#menu-switch').removeClass('hide');
    };
});
```

This way it can catch the events of browser resizing and every time the user resizes its browser the variable width will get a new value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check when page is load and when is resize or scroll:

```
var changeMe = function(){
   var $width = $(document).width();
     if ($width <= 768){
      $('header').addClass('hide');
      $('#menu-switch').removeClass('hide');
    };
};
/* On ready */
$(document).ready(function(){changeMe();});
/* On resize */
$(window).resize(function(){changeMe();});
/* On scroll */
$(document).scroll(function(){changeMe();});
```

This work 100%.

But you can use CSS3 for this problem:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    header {
       display: none;
    }
    #menu-switch {
       display: block;
    }
}
```

Just include CSS switcers AFTER your main style and change ONLY what you need.